# How to avoid "Can't mass-assign protected attributes" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

Even though I added accepts_nested_attributes_for to my model.
it still says "Can't mass-assign protected attributes"
What else am I supposed to do in order to avoid this???

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :username 
  validates_uniqueness_of :username 
  validates_length_of :username, :within => 4..10

  acts_as_messageable

  has_one :user_profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :user_profile_attributes

  def mailboxer_email(message)
    email
  end

#  def name
#    email
#  end

end
```

models/user_profile.rb

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
 attr_accessible :nickname
end
```

views/registration/edit.html.erb

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :nickname %><br />
    <%= f.fields_for :nickname_attributes, @user.user_profile do |user_profile| %>
    <%= user_profile.text_field :nickname %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %></div>

<%= recaptcha_tags :display => {:theme => 'red'} %>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>.</p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`attr_accessible` defines the attributes you want the user to be able to mass assign. Just make sure it has all the attributes you want in there.

To be fair, you can remove `attr_accessible` if you don't care about it and the error will disappear (but all your model fields will be mass assignable).

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help in my case :( it seems its all because I'm using the gem 'Devise' According to this link<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037203/nested-form-with-devise> it looks like I need to add  @user.build_user_profile.   But what the problem is that devise doesn't create user_controller so there is no file to edit.

Answer (score 1):

in edit.html.erb

wrong:

```
f.fields_for :nickname_attributes,
```

correct:

```
f.fields_for :user_profile_attributes,
```